# No puedo llamar a métodos de una Custom View Android

Tags: android

Estoy trabajando en **Android** y tengo un problemita que no he podido solucionar. Yo cree una `view` personalizada (La clase es `public Lienzo extends View`), es una aplicacion para **pintar en la pantalla**, el problema es que cuanto quiero cambiar el tamanio del pincel o llamar cualquier metodo desde la activity la app se detiene por un **NullPointerException**, yo se que es un problema con la referencia a el objeto.

PD: Yo tengo creada la variable de tipo Lienzo (`private Lienzo lienzo`) y tambien hago la referencia a la view (`lienzo = (Lienzo) findViewById(R.id.lienzo);`)

El error se da en `lienzo.cualquierMetodo();`

**Solución:**

Me falto pasar un parametro AttributeSet en el constructor de la View:

**Incorrecto:**

```
public Lienzo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }
```

**Correcto:**

```
public Lienzo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, **attrs**);
    }
```

Comment: Puedes ponernos el codigo de la clase, o de la zona donde te da el error? Es demasiada poca informacion.

Comment: Amigos ya solucione el error, y me siento tan tontin jeje. En el constructor de la view me falto pasarle un parametro AttributeSet

Comment: @AntonioRodriguez Puedes publicar una respuesta con la solución y dentro de poco la puedes marcar como correcta, sería de ayuda si alguien tiene el mismo problema :)

Comment: Entonces el error no era en lienzo.cualquierMetodo(); era especifically en el constructor de la clase Lienzo.

Answer (score 2):

**Solucionado:** el error esta en el constructor de la view personalizada, he olvidado enviar los parametros **AttributeSet** al constructor principal de la clase View.

**Incorrecto:**

```
public Lienzo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context);
    }
```

Solo le pasa el atributo context en el super(), faltando el atributo attrs.

**Correcto:**

```
public Lienzo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }
```

Envia los argumentos correspondientes al constructor de la View, que son **Context context y AttributeSet attrs**.